# Cannot install lsphp74-imagick: unmet dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, php, litespeed

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS instance running on Amazon Lightsail and I have trouble installing **lsphp74-imagick**.

```
$ sudo apt install lsphp74-imagick
```

Response:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
lsphp74-imagick : 
Depends: libmagickcore-6.q16-3 (>= 8:6.9.6.8) but it is not installable               
Depends: libmagickwand-6.q16-3 (>= 8:6.9.6.8) but it is not installable
Recommends: ttf-dejavu-core but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

For libmagickcore I get the following:

```
$ sudo apt install libmagickcore-6.q16-3
..
E: Package 'libmagickcore-6.q16-3' has no installation candidate
```

Not sure where to go from here. Did anyone run into this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `wget -O - http://rpms.litespeedtech.com/debian/enable_lst_debian_repo.sh | bash` try that first

Comment: unfortunately that did not help

Comment: more verbose output

Comment: Thank you for pointing me the right direction. It was a repo issue. After a fresh install I tried the following and it worked without any issue:
```wget -qO - https://rpms.litespeedtech.com/debian/lst_repo.gpg | sudo apt-key add - ``` then ```echo "deb http://rpms.litespeedtech.com/debian/ focal main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openlitespeed.list```

Comment: I will add tomorrow it as answer and I hope you can accept it then ;)

Comment: You can add it then I'll accept it but please give at least a vote to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Original Issue sounded like an Repository issue. And it was so.

To fix that:

## Install automatically the Repository

```sh
wget -O - http://rpms.litespeedtech.com/debian/enable_lst_debian_repo.sh | bash
```

## Fix Manually

You may find outdated lines with

```sh
grep -Ri litespeedtech /etc/apt/*
```

## Install the GPG Keys and Sources

```sh
wget -qO - https://rpms.litespeedtech.com/debian/lst_repo.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo echo "deb http://rpms.litespeedtech.com/debian/ focal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openlitespeed.list
```

then run `apt-get update` and it should be gone.